# range of selected text is different from range of actual html attributed string

Tags: ios, swift, textview, nsattributedstring

range of selected text is different from the range of actual HTML attributed string, when i select text in textview view it gives the range of selected text whereas in real the attributed string text range is different the tags are read-only property and are read by an attributed string
the
I want to calculate the actual range of html attributed string for the selected text in textview

actual string stored in a database with HTML tags is

String =  `He created every plant of the field in the earth and a <font style="background-color:#e99898;">any herb of the field </font>hat grows even before He had caused it to rain on the earth or created any man to work the ground;`

using this extension to find range of selected text in textview

```
extension UITextInput {
    var selectedRange: NSRange? {
        guard let range = selectedTextRange else { return nil }
        let location = offset(from: beginningOfDocument, to: range.start)
        let length = offset(from: range.start, to: range.end)
        return NSRange(location: location, length: length)
    }
}
```

[see screenshot for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCWEw.png)

Comment: It's unclear, how is called that? Why don't you use already the `selectedRange` of `UITextView`? Could it be an issue because you are accessing the HTML string (with the HTML tag), and not the nsattributedstring.string where HTML tags have been parsed and don't appear in the string?

Comment: yes the tags are not appearing in the string so selected range does not give the exact range of string with html tags it gives range for text selected in textview ( text location which is selected in textview)

Comment: But how do you call/read that value? Why don't you already exiting property of UITextView?

Comment: let AttributedText =  convertingHtmlTextToAttributedString(htmlText: "Some String with html tags") )

  self.verseTextView.attributedText = AttributedText

Comment: Where is called your implementation of `selectedRange`? You use a `UITextView`, no? Why not using already existing `selectedRange` property then? That's the unclear parts...

Comment: both give same result

Comment: UITextView.selectedRange should work, I don't remember having seen an issue about selection on it... Are you sure you aren't calling your "override“?